# Reduce redundant code by optimizing of appendRow() App script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a project where I shall send data from my app to a google spreadsheet in 2 sheets through app script.

I set up a paraphrase to secure the connection. `Hkey`

I have a lot of data to send like computer1,brand1,cpu1,ram1,computer2,brand2,cpu2,ram2 until 20.

my first version of the code comprise a lot of data like below:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var Sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var Region = e.parameter.Region ; 
  var Place = e.parameter.Place ;
  var Staff = e.parameter.Staff ;

  var computer1 = e.parameter.computer1;
  var brand1 = e.parameter.brand1;
  var cpu1 = e.parameter.cpu1;
  var ram1 = e.parameter.ram1;

  var computer2 = e.parameter.computer2;
  var brand2 = e.parameter.brand2;
  var cpu2 = e.parameter.cpu2;
  var ram2 = e.parameter.ram2;

  var Hkey = e.parameter.Hkey;

if (Hkey == 'AB12xyz') {
  sheet1.appendRow(Region, Place, Staff, computer, brand, cpu, ram);
  Sheet2.appendRow(Region, Place, Staff, computer, brand, cpu, ram);
  }
}
```

Then I optimised the code to avoid repeated tasks.
where if the `computer` is true, then append `computer1,brand1,cpu1,ram1` and so on...until `computer20,brand20,cpu20,ram20`

Optimised code :

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var Sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var ID = "FS" + new Date("GMT+4", "ddMM");
  
  var Region = e.parameter.Region ; 
  var Place = e.parameter.Place ;
  var Staff = e.parameter.Staff ;
  var Shop = e.parameter.Shop;
  var Location = e.parameter.Location ;
  var Date_Checked = e.parameter.Date_Checked ;
  var Time_Checked = e.parameter.Time_Checked ;
  var Link = "check your inbox" ;
  var Remarks = e.parameter.Remarks ;

  var Hkey = e.parameter.Hkey;

  if (Hkey == 'AB12xyz') {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
      var computer = e.parameter['computer' + i];
      var brand = e.parameter['brand' + i];
      var cpu = e.parameter['cpu' + i];
      var ram = e.parameter['ram' + i];

      if (computer) {
        var row = [ID,Region,Place,Staff,Shop,Location, Date_Checked,Time_Checked,Link,Remarks];
        sheet1.appendRow(row, computer, brand, cpu, ram);
        Sheet2.appendRow(row, computer, brand, cpu, ram);
       
      }
    }
```

**The issue is that nothing is appended on the 2 sheets of the spreadsheet.
When checking the script deployment overview, I got only failures.**

Comment: appendRow accepts an Array of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to modify your script as a simple script.
- You want to understand the reason for `The issue is that nothing is appended on the 2 sheets of the spreadsheet. When checking the script deployment overview, I got only failures.`.

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, at `appendRow(row, computer, brand, cpu, ram)`, `row` is 1 dimensional array and the values of `computer, brand, cpu, ram` are string.
- I think that `new Date("GMT+4", "ddMM")` of `var ID = "FS" + new Date("GMT+4", "ddMM");` returns "Invalid Date".

When these points are reflected in your bottom script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var ID = "FS" + new Date("GMT+4", "ddMM");
```

#### To:

```
var ID = "FS" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMM");
```

and

#### From:

```
sheet1.appendRow(row, computer, brand, cpu, ram);
Sheet2.appendRow(row, computer, brand, cpu, ram);
```

#### To:

```
sheet1.appendRow([...row, computer, brand, cpu, ram]);
Sheet2.appendRow([...row, computer, brand, cpu, ram]);
```

This is the answer to your 2nd question. About your 1st question, in this case, how about the following modification?

When `appendRow` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var ID = "FS" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMM");
  var Link = "check your inbox";
  const { Region, Place, Staff, Shop, Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Remarks, Hkey } = e.parameter;
  const row = [ID, Region, Place, Staff, Shop, Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Link, Remarks];
  if (Hkey == 'AB12xyz') {
    const res = [...Array(20)].reduce((ar, _, h) => {
      var i = h + 1;
      var computer = e.parameter['computer' + i];
      if (computer) {
        ar.push([...row, computer, ...['brand', 'cpu', 'ram'].map(f => e.parameter[`${f}${i}`] || "")]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    if (res.length == 0) return;
    [sheet1, sheet2].forEach(sheet => sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res));
  }
}
```

### Added:

From `FYI, for the time format, its work fine.`, I understood that your expected date value could be retrieved. About `still didn't append :(` and`, when I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I noticed that the sheet names of your provided Spreadsheet are not "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". Those were "Stocks" and "Stocks_Synthesis", respectively. I'm worried that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, please modify my proposed script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Stocks"); // Modified
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Stocks_Synthesis'); // Modified
  var ID = "FS" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMM");
  var Link = "check your inbox";
  const { Region, Place, Staff, Shop, Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Remarks, Hkey } = e.parameter;
  const row = [ID, Region, Place, Staff, Shop, Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Link, Remarks];
  if (Hkey == 'AB12xyz') {
    const res = [...Array(20)].reduce((ar, _, h) => {
      var i = h + 1;
      var computer = e.parameter['computer' + i];
      if (computer) {
        ar.push([...row, computer, ...['brand', 'cpu', 'ram'].map(f => e.parameter[`${f}${i}`] || "")]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    if (res.length == 0) return;
    [sheet1, sheet2].forEach(sheet => sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res));
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok"); // This is a sample response value.
}
```

And, please reflect this modified script to the Web Apps. And, when you test this, please request the following Web Apps URL including the query parameter using your browser. By this, the values are appended to both sheets.

In this case, please replace `{deploymentId}` with your value.

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId}/exec?Region=Region&Place=Place&Staff=Staff&Shop=Shop&Location=Location&Date_Checked=Date_Checked&Time_Checked=Time_Checked&Remarks=Remarks&Hkey=AB12xyz&computer1=computer1&brand1=brand1&cpu1=cpu1&ram1=ram1&computer2=computer2&brand2=brand2&cpu2=cpu2&ram2=ram2&computer3=computer3&brand3=brand3&cpu3=cpu3&ram3=ram3&computer4=computer4&brand4=brand4&cpu4=cpu4&ram4=ram4&computer5=computer5&brand5=brand5&cpu5=cpu5&ram5=ram5&computer6=computer6&brand6=brand6&cpu6=cpu6&ram6=ram6&computer7=computer7&brand7=brand7&cpu7=cpu7&ram7=ram7&computer8=computer8&brand8=brand8&cpu8=cpu8&ram8=ram8&computer9=computer9&brand9=brand9&cpu9=cpu9&ram9=ram9&computer10=computer10&brand10=brand10&cpu10=cpu10&ram10=ram10&computer11=computer11&brand11=brand11&cpu11=cpu11&ram11=ram11&computer12=computer12&brand12=brand12&cpu12=cpu12&ram12=ram12&computer13=computer13&brand13=brand13&cpu13=cpu13&ram13=ram13&computer14=computer14&brand14=brand14&cpu14=cpu14&ram14=ram14&computer15=computer15&brand15=brand15&cpu15=cpu15&ram15=ram15&computer16=computer16&brand16=brand16&cpu16=cpu16&ram16=ram16&computer17=computer17&brand17=brand17&cpu17=cpu17&ram17=ram17&computer18=computer18&brand18=brand18&cpu18=cpu18&ram18=ram18&computer19=computer19&brand19=brand19&cpu19=cpu19&ram19=ram19&computer20=computer20&brand20=brand20&cpu20=cpu20&ram20=ram20
```

When I tested this on your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that the values are appended to both sheets. Please test it again.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: Hello Tanaike, still didn't append :(

Comment: FYI, for the time format, its work fine.

Comment: @P.J Thank you for replying. About `Hello Tanaike, still didn't append :(`, I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanaike, works like a charm.
I plan to optimize the code as follows in order to append the numbered tags in different line.
`ID, Region, Place, Staff, Shop, Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Link, Remarks with computer1, brand 1....`



`ID, Region, Place, Staff, Shop, Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Link, Remarks with computer2, brand 2....`

Hope that one will works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var ID = "FS" +  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+4", "ddMM");//from Tanaikes answer
  var b = e.parameter.Region;
  var c = e.parameter.Place;
  var d = e.parameter.Staff;
  var e = e.parameter.Shop;
  var f = e.parameter.Location;
  var g = e.parameter.Date_Checked;
  var h = e.parameter.Time_Checked;
  var i = "check your inbox";
  var j = e.parameter.Remarks;
  var row = [ID, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j];
  if (e.parameter.Hkey == 'AB12xyz') {
    for (var n = 1; n <= 20; n++) {
      var computer = e.parameter['computer' + n];
      var brand = e.parameter['brand' + n];
      var cpu = e.parameter['cpu' + n];
      var ram = e.parameter['ram' + n];
      let add = [computer, brand, cpu, ram];
      if (computer) {
        let r = row.concat(add);
        sh1.appendRow(r);
        sh2.appendRow(r);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Cooper, tried and the information didn't append to the sheet.

Comment: Hello Cooper, tried and  the tags `computer1` , `computer2` sent to the script didn't append to the sheet. :(

Comment: Please supply and copiable table of data so that we can do our own debugging or debug it yourself.

Comment: The only code I'm currently using is the provided code.
I send the data from app inventor 2 with the doGet blocks to retrieve the `Hkey` after which the data is appended to the google sheet which the app script is bound to.
Link of spreadsheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cbtb3KPa0BHnjnitVQsvqmgTK2CtAZekbuinD9e6XDY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't follow links to spreadsheets.  I'd put a table of data instead.