# Custom ID counter discrepancies

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that create a unique id per entry in a google sheet.

When sending to data to two google sheets at once, I added a time stamp and a unique ID.

I noticed discrepancies in the ID count as it was supposed to iterate until 365 then will reset.

For appending data, I got help from
[Reduce redundant code by optimizing of appendRow() App script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843196/reduce-redundant-code-by-optimizing-of-appendrow-app-script/76844031?noredirect=1#comment135477473_76844031)

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var counter = scriptProperties.getProperty('counter') || 0;
  var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMM");
  var zero = (counter < 365) ? '0' : '';
  var ID = "FS" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
  if (counter > 99) counter = 0;
  scriptProperties.setProperty('counter', counter);
```

**But, I noticed that it skip some numbers a different intervals as i is not suppose to.**

[image]

[image]

Added complete code :

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Stocks");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Stocks_Synthesis');

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var counter = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty('counter')) || 0;
  //var counter = scriptProperties.getProperty('counter') || 0;
  var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMM");
  var zero = (counter < 365) ? '0' : '';
  var ID = "FS" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
  if (counter > 99) counter = 0;
  scriptProperties.setProperty('counter', counter);

  var TimeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
  var Link = "check your inbox";
  const { Region, Place, Staff, Shop, Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Remarks, Hkey } = e.parameter;
  const row = [TimeStamp, ID, Region, Place, Staff, Shop, Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Link, Remarks];

  if (Hkey == 'AB12xyz') {
    const res = [...Array(20)].reduce((ar, _, h) => {
      var i = h + 1;
      var computer = e.parameter['computer' + i];
      if (computer) {
        ar.push([...row, computer, ...['brand', 'cpu', 'ram'].map(f => e.parameter[`${f}${i}`] || "")]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    if (res.length == 0) return;
    [sheet1, sheet2].forEach(sheet => sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res));
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok"); 
}
```

Comment: scriptProperties stores everything as a string

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var counter = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty('counter')) || 0;
```

I just ran the following code and I don't see any counter discrepancies but perhaps I am missing something.

code ran:

```
function lfunko(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  props.setProperty("counter", '');
  sh.clearContents();
  var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMM");
  let arr = [];
  [...new Array(100)].forEach((i) => {
    var counter = Number(props.getProperty('counter')) || 0;
    var zero = (counter < 365) ? '0' : '';
    var ID = "FS" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
    if (counter > 99) counter = 0;
    props.setProperty('counter', counter);
    arr.push([ID, counter]);
  })
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  sh.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

results:

| FS130800 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| FS130801 | 2 |
| FS130802 | 3 |
| FS130803 | 4 |
| FS130804 | 5 |
| FS130805 | 6 |
| FS130806 | 7 |
| FS130807 | 8 |
| FS130808 | 9 |
| FS130809 | 10 |
| FS1308010 | 11 |
| FS1308011 | 12 |
| FS1308012 | 13 |
| FS1308013 | 14 |
| FS1308014 | 15 |
| FS1308015 | 16 |
| FS1308016 | 17 |
| FS1308017 | 18 |
| FS1308018 | 19 |
| FS1308019 | 20 |
| FS1308020 | 21 |
| FS1308021 | 22 |
| FS1308022 | 23 |
| FS1308023 | 24 |
| FS1308024 | 25 |
| FS1308025 | 26 |
| FS1308026 | 27 |
| FS1308027 | 28 |
| FS1308028 | 29 |
| FS1308029 | 30 |
| FS1308030 | 31 |
| FS1308031 | 32 |
| FS1308032 | 33 |
| FS1308033 | 34 |
| FS1308034 | 35 |
| FS1308035 | 36 |
| FS1308036 | 37 |
| FS1308037 | 38 |
| FS1308038 | 39 |
| FS1308039 | 40 |
| FS1308040 | 41 |
| FS1308041 | 42 |
| FS1308042 | 43 |
| FS1308043 | 44 |
| FS1308044 | 45 |
| FS1308045 | 46 |
| FS1308046 | 47 |
| FS1308047 | 48 |
| FS1308048 | 49 |
| FS1308049 | 50 |
| FS1308050 | 51 |
| FS1308051 | 52 |
| FS1308052 | 53 |
| FS1308053 | 54 |
| FS1308054 | 55 |
| FS1308055 | 56 |
| FS1308056 | 57 |
| FS1308057 | 58 |
| FS1308058 | 59 |
| FS1308059 | 60 |
| FS1308060 | 61 |
| FS1308061 | 62 |
| FS1308062 | 63 |
| FS1308063 | 64 |
| FS1308064 | 65 |
| FS1308065 | 66 |
| FS1308066 | 67 |
| FS1308067 | 68 |
| FS1308068 | 69 |
| FS1308069 | 70 |
| FS1308070 | 71 |
| FS1308071 | 72 |
| FS1308072 | 73 |
| FS1308073 | 74 |
| FS1308074 | 75 |
| FS1308075 | 76 |
| FS1308076 | 77 |
| FS1308077 | 78 |
| FS1308078 | 79 |
| FS1308079 | 80 |
| FS1308080 | 81 |
| FS1308081 | 82 |
| FS1308082 | 83 |
| FS1308083 | 84 |
| FS1308084 | 85 |
| FS1308085 | 86 |
| FS1308086 | 87 |
| FS1308087 | 88 |
| FS1308088 | 89 |
| FS1308089 | 90 |
| FS1308090 | 91 |
| FS1308091 | 92 |
| FS1308092 | 93 |
| FS1308093 | 94 |
| FS1308094 | 95 |
| FS1308095 | 96 |
| FS1308096 | 97 |
| FS1308097 | 98 |
| FS1308098 | 99 |
| FS1308099 | 0 |

Comment: Just tested, same situation

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that I can test the code and I'll look into it.

Comment: I just added the complete code in my post

Comment: When sending same data simultaneously, the discrepancies occurred.

I tried with lockservice but the issue remain.