# Google Apps Script: Second e.parameter Not Functioning as Expected

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello trust you are doing well

My app send a data to a google sheet and it append the data followed by and ID and a timestamp.

I use a key as parameter where if the hkey 1 is inputted the data will go in a one sheet and if the hkey is 2 it will go in another sheet.

for the hkey 1 it works but for the hkey 2 I got errors.

FYI : When appending data, for either hkey 1 or 2, it will append data to 2 sheets for redundancy.

Here is my code :

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var StocksSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stocks");
  var OrdersSheets = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");
  
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var counter = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty('counter')) || 0;
  //var counter = scriptProperties.getProperty('counter') || 0;
  var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMM");
  var zero = (counter < 365) ? '0' : '';
  var ID = "FS" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
  var IDP = "FP" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
  if (counter > 99) counter = 0;
  scriptProperties.setProperty('counter', counter);

  var TimeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
  var LinkS = "https://drive.google.com/drive/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var LinkP = "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const { Region, Place, Staff, Shop_Representative, Product_Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Remarks, Hkey, RemarksP, Date_Ordered, Time_Ordered, Date_of_Delivery } = e.parameter;
  const rowS = [TimeStamp, ID, Region, Place, Staff, Shop_Representative, Product_Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Remarks, LinkS];
  const rowP = [TimeStamp, IDP, Region, Place, Staff, Shop_Representative, Date_Ordered, Time_Ordered, Date_of_Delivery, LinkP, RemarksP];

  if (Hkey == '123') {
    const res = [...Array(20)].reduce((ar, _, h) => {
      var i = h + 1;
      var Product = e.parameter['Product' + i];
      if (Product) {
        ar.push([...rowS, Product, ...['Filling', 'Quantity', 'Expiry'].map(f => e.parameter[`${f}${i}`] || "")]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
        
    if (res.length == 0) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Stock not uploaded, please retry");
    }
    
    try {

      StocksSheet.getRange(StocksSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      var StocksLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Stocks_Logs");
      StocksLogs.getRange(StocksLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Your stock had been inputed with ID " + ID);

    } catch (error) {
      
      var StocksLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Stocks_Logs");
      StocksLogs.getRange(StocksLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("Database issue detected for stock with ID:" +ID+  ". Please coordinate with the administrator for resolution.");
    }    
  } 
  
  if(Hkey == '456') {
    const res = [...Array(12)].reduce((ar, _, h) => {
      var i = h + 1;
      var Product = e.parameter['Product' + i];
      if (Product) {
        ar.push([...rowP, Product, ...['Filling', 'Quantity', 'Discount'].map(f => e.parameter[`${f}${i}`] || "")]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
        
    if (res.length == 0) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Order not uploaded, please retry");
    }
    
    try {

      OrdersSheets.getRange(OrdersSheets.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      var OrdersLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Orders_Logs");
      OrdersLogs.getRange(OrdersLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Your order had been inputed with ID " + IDP);

      } catch (error) {
      
      var OrdersLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Orders_Logs");
      OrdersLogs.getRange(OrdersLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Database issue detected for order with ID:" +IDP+  ". Please coordinate with the administrator for resolution.");
    } 
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Please check check your app version")
  }
}
```

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var StocksSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stocks");
  var OrdersSheets = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");
  
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var counter = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty('counter')) || 0;
  //var counter = scriptProperties.getProperty('counter') || 0;
  var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMM");
  var zero = (counter < 365) ? '0' : '';
  var ID = "FS" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
  var IDP = "FP" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
  if (counter > 99) counter = 0;
  scriptProperties.setProperty('counter', counter);

  var TimeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
  var LinkS = "https://drive.google.com/drive/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var LinkP = "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const { Region, Place, Staff, Shop_Representative, Product_Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Remarks, Hkey, RemarksP, Date_Ordered, Time_Ordered, Date_of_Delivery } = e.parameter;
  const rowS = [TimeStamp, ID, Region, Place, Staff, Shop_Representative, Product_Location, Date_Checked, Time_Checked, Remarks, LinkS];
  const rowP = [TimeStamp, IDP, Region, Place, Staff, Shop_Representative, Date_Ordered, Time_Ordered, Date_of_Delivery, LinkP, RemarksP];
```

This part below works fine
Reference to question asked : [Reduce redundant code by optimizing of appendRow() App script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843196/reduce-redundant-code-by-optimizing-of-appendrow-app-script?noredirect=1#comment135469573_76843196)

```
  if (Hkey == '123') {
    const res = [...Array(20)].reduce((ar, _, h) => {
      var i = h + 1;
      var Product = e.parameter['Product' + i];
      if (Product) {
        ar.push([...rowS, Product, ...['Filling', 'Quantity', 'Expiry'].map(f => e.parameter[`${f}${i}`] || "")]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
        
    if (res.length == 0) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Stock not uploaded, please retry");
    }
    
    try {

      StocksSheet.getRange(StocksSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      var StocksLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Stocks_Logs");
      StocksLogs.getRange(StocksLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Your stock had been inputed with ID " + ID);

    } catch (error) {
      
      var StocksLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Stocks_Logs");
      StocksLogs.getRange(StocksLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("Database issue detected for stock with ID:" +ID+  ". Please coordinate with the administrator for resolution.");
    }    
  }
```

This part did not work, it did not append data to the google sheets

```
  if(Hkey == '456') {
    const res = [...Array(12)].reduce((ar, _, h) => {
      var i = h + 1;
      var Product = e.parameter['Product' + i];
      if (Product) {
        ar.push([...rowP, Product, ...['Filling', 'Quantity', 'Discount'].map(f => e.parameter[`${f}${i}`] || "")]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
        
    if (res.length == 0) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Order not uploaded, please retry");
    }
    
    try {

      OrdersSheets.getRange(OrdersSheets.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      var OrdersLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Orders_Logs");
      OrdersLogs.getRange(OrdersLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Your order had been inputed with ID " + IDP);

      } catch (error) {
      
      var OrdersLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Orders_Logs");
      OrdersLogs.getRange(OrdersLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Database issue detected for order with ID:" +IDP+  ". Please coordinate with the administrator for resolution.");
    } 
  }
```

This part is for error with Hkey

```
else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Please check check your app version")
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And, can you provide whole script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, the code is base on the previously asked question you helped me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843196/reduce-redundant-code-by-optimizing-of-appendrow-app-script/76844031?noredirect=1#comment135477473_76844031

I just added another parameter to append data to 2 other sheets
eg. if (Hkey == '123'), it will append data to sheets StocksSheet and StocksLogs
where if (Hkey == '456'), it will append data to sheets OrdersSheets and OrdersLogs.

The issue is that only (Hkey == '123') append data but with (Hkey == '456') I got errors and i did not append

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. Can you provide whole script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, I edited the code to clarify the part with issues as  it is the complete code.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. Your showing script is your whole script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes it is the whole script

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Yes it is the whole script`, I would like to try to think of your question. When I find a solution, I would like to post it as an answer.

Comment: ```When I find a solution, I would like to post it as an answer.``` Of course, no issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, do you have an error returned by Apps Script (if so, please write it in the post) or is it just that it does not behave as expected ?

Comment: Hello @ValLeNain, now  I on got the return only  and the data is not appended

```
else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Please check check your app version")
  }
} 
```

Comment: are you sure that `Hkey` has the value you expect ? I don't see in the code where it gets its value from... is it a constant outside the functions ?

Comment: Yes the ```Hkey``` has the expected value.
It is a parameter sent from my app.

Comment: Have yu tried testing it with UrlFetchApp?  Do you have some test data for something like that?  If you could provide that it would make your example reproducible and make it possible for us to test.

Comment: I tested the code with data that I made up and it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot confirm problem with code. I'd guess the problem is probably in your data

I modified the code as follows:

This is the test code for sh2

```
function testDG() {
  var e = { parameter: { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4, E: 5, F: 6, G: 7, H: 8, I: "456", J: 9, K: 10, L: 11, M: 12, X: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], Y: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], Z: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], Product1: "one", Product2: "two", Product3: "three", Product4: "four", Product5: "five", Product6: "six", Product7: "seven", Product8: "eight", Product9: "nine" }};
  doGet(e);
}

function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var scrprops = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var counter = Number(scrprops.getProperty('counter')) || 0;
  var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMM");
  var zero = (counter < 365) ? '0' : '';
  var ID = "FS" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
  var IDP = "FP" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
  if (counter > 99) counter = 0;
  scrprops.setProperty('counter', counter);

  var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
  var Link1 = "https://drive.google.com/drive/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var Link2 = "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M } = e.parameter;
  const rowS = [ts, ID, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, Link1];
  const rowP = [ts, IDP, A, B, C, D, K, L, M, Link2, J];

  if (I == '123') {
    const res = [...Array(9)].reduce((ar, _, h) => {
      var i = h + 1;
      var Product = e.parameter['Product' + i];
      if (Product) {
        ar.push([...rowS, Product, ...['X', 'Y', 'Z'].map(f => e.parameter[`${f}${i}`] || "")]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);

    if (res.length == 0) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Stock not uploaded, please retry");
    }

    try {

      sh1.getRange(sh1.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      //var StocksLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Stocks_Logs");
      //StocksLogs.getRange(StocksLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      //return ContentService.createTextOutput("Your stock had been inputed with ID " + ID);

    } catch (error) {

      //var StocksLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Stocks_Logs");
      //StocksLogs.getRange(StocksLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      //return ContentService.createTextOutput("Database issue detected for stock with ID:" + ID + ". Please coordinate with the administrator for resolution.");
    }
  }

  if (I == '456') {
    const res = [...Array(9)].reduce((ar, _, h) => {
      var i = h + 1;
      var Product = e.parameter['Product' + i];
      if (Product) {
        ar.push([...rowP, Product, ...['X', 'Y', 'Z'].map(f => e.parameter[`${f}${i}`] || "")]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);

    if (res.length == 0) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Order not uploaded, please retry");
    }

    try {

      sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      var OrdersLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Orders_Logs");
      //OrdersLogs.getRange(OrdersLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      //return ContentService.createTextOutput("Your order had been inputed with ID " + IDP);

    } catch (error) {

      //var OrdersLogs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Orders_Logs");
      //OrdersLogs.getRange(OrdersLogs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      //return ContentService.createTextOutput("Database issue detected for order with ID:" + IDP + ". Please /coordinate with the administrator for resolution.");
    }
  } else {
    //return ContentService.createTextOutput("Please check check your app version")
  }
}
```

The code is able to write to both sheets based upon the value in I